# Many view controllers from uiTableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

How to make in xcode 5 many viewControllers connected with one cell in UITableView? I'd like to make this because every cells are deferent (1) with photo, 2) with UIWebView, 3) viewController). After user taps on cell system must know which UIController it should fire up. For better view I've attached screenshot. How to make it all with storyboard?

[image]

How to connect this three controllers to one table cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect more than one segue to a cell. If you need to go to one of a number of controllers based on which cell you select, you should make the segues from the controller itself, and then use logic in didSelectRowAtIndexPath to decide which segue to perform. You can connect as many segues as you want from the controller, and when they're set up that way, you have to initiate them by calling performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:.

Comment: Tell me please if I understand it the right way: When user click cell I must recognise what type is it and then trigger the right controller programatically, right?